# Want to create own class String

Tags: c++, string, class, pointers, attributes

I'm making an own class String in C++.

I have a problem with this:

```
class String {
    char* arr;
    int len;

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& s, const String& c) {
        return s << c.arr;
    }

    Public:
        String() {
            arr = NULL;
            len = 0;
        }
        String(const char* name) {
            *arr = *name;
        }
}
```

In main I have this:

```
String *s = new String("abcde"); 
    cout << *s << endl;
```

The problem is that the compilator shows me this:

> Bus error : 10

I'm working on a mac, using the terminal with g++.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
String(const char* name) {
    *arr = *name;
//  ^^^^
}
```

Is dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, thus giving you undefined behavior. I guess what you actually want to do is something like this:

```
#include <cstring> // For strlen() and strcpy()

String(const char* name) {
    len = strlen(name);
    arr = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy(arr, name);
}
```

Also, do not forget to provide a destructor for cleanup, a copy constructor, and a copy assignment operator - and if working in C++11, also a move constructor and a move assignment operator.